# Is there any git hooks that I can get commit message and add something to commit?

Tags: git

I want to generate a CHANGELOG.md file before commit, and this file should contain latest commit info.
But I can't get commit message in `pre-commit` nor add file to commit in `commit-msg`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you give more details about what info you want to add in CHANGELOD.md ?

Comment: I want to use git metadata and git commit history to generate a CHANGELOG.md automatically, using tools like conventional-changelog.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach: ask the user about future commit message, add the message to the `CHANGELOD.md`, `git add CHANGELOD.md` to the index, and then run `git commit` with option(s) `-m` or `-F` to pass the commit message to `git commit`. That way you ask the user about commit message only once and use the message everywhere you need it.

You can create a git alias, a shell script or a shell function to do all of this at once.